# BCP queryout file to FTP server

Tags: sql, ftp

I am querying a set of tables and generating XML from it. I can then use xp_cmdshell to create a file on the disk and this works well.

`EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT MyXML FROM ##Orders" queryout "C:\Temp\OrderFile.xml" -T -c -t,'`

Instead of saving to the local disk, how can I amend this to save to a location on an FTP server instead?

Comment: Presumably you've tried to use the share name eg `"\\servername\sharename\filename.xml"` - what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass credentials for the FTP. I am using Trusted Connection for SQL

Comment: Also, I tried that, but I get this error: ```Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file``` I even tried mapping the location as a network drive, so that I can put ```Y:\filename.xml``` in the script. The mapped drive works fine from Windows Explorer, but produces the same error in the script

Comment: `EXEC xp_cmdshell` executes any command, right? So just google for any example how to upload a file to FTP from commandline and do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (Unable to open BCP host data-file) on my local machine. For me, it turned out that the file path was too long. When the destination path was shorter, it started working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33213689)